# Django 1.8: AttributeError at /: 'str' object has no attribute 'copy'

Tags: python, django

I've been trying out Django 1.8.1. So far it's been good until I tested it. When I go to the address (`localhost:8000`) where Django is serving the files, I get the error:

`AttributeError at /:
'str' object has no attribute 'copy'`

I have one app called `fb_auth` in Django. This is the directory tree.

`/path/to/project/directory
|
---.gitignore
|
---project_foo
   |
   ---project_foo
   ---fb_auth
   ---templates
   ---<stuff>`

In the traceback, I could see this highlighted line which is from my view.

`return render(request, 'login.html')`

Here's my `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect, render    
from django.contrib.auth import logout as auth_logout    
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required    

def login(request):    
    return render(request, 'login.html')    

@login_required(login_url='/')    
def vote(request):    
    return render_to_response('vote.html')    

def logout(request):     
    auth_logout(request)    
    return redirect('/')
```

Here's my `urls.py` (in case this helps):

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url('', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
    url(r'^$', 'fb_auth.views.login'),
    url(r'^vote/$', 'fb_auth.views.vote'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'fb_auth.views.logout'),
]
```

Here's my `login.html`:

```
{% if user and not user.is_anonymous %}
    <a>Hello, {{ user.get_full_name }}!</a>
    <br>
    <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Login with Facebook</a>
{% endif %}
```

This is my `vote.html` (for the moment):

```
<h1>Hello vote test</h1>
<p>    
    <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
</p>
```

And here's the traceback:

```
File "/home/seanballais/Code/Projects/SAElections/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response    
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)    
File "/home/seanballais/Code/Projects/SAElections/SAElections/fb_auth/views.py" in login    
  6.     return render(request, 'login.html')    
File "/home/seanballais/Code/Projects/SAElections/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render    
  67.             template_name, context, request=request, using=using)    
File "/home/seanballais/Code/Projects/SAElections/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string    
  98.             template = get_template(template_name, using=using)    
File "/home/seanballais/Code/Projects/SAElections/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template    
  29.     engines = _engine_list(using)    
File "/home/seanballais/Code/Projects/SAElections/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in _engine_list    
  144.     return engines.all() if using is None else [engines[using]]    
File "/home/seanballais/Code/Projects/SAElections/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/utils.py" in all    
  108.         return [self[alias] for alias in self]    
File "/home/seanballais/Code/Projects/SAElections/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/utils.py" in __iter__    
  105.         return iter(self.templates)    
File "/home/seanballais/Code/Projects/SAElections/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __get__    
  60.         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)    
File "/home/seanballais/Code/Projects/SAElections/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/utils.py" in templates    
  54.             tpl = tpl.copy()            

Exception Type: AttributeError at /    
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

EDIT: Added in my `urls.py`, and the traceback.

I hope this helps. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks! :)

Comment: You have a traceback, you should post it here.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot to include the traceback. Including it now.

Comment: Check [TEMPLATES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#templates) on settings. Be sure is is a list.

Comment: I did that already and it worked. I found the solution. Going to answer my own question in case others would encounter this type of error message.

Comment: @SeanfrancisBallais, nice. I post it as solution.

Comment: Actually, I discovered that 'should-be-a-list' thing on my own but I didn't know that it should've been a list. So yeah. Thanks a lot. You taught me something. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be sure that [TEMPLATES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#templates) on settings is a list.

Quoting django docs:

> TEMPLATES
>
> New in Django 1.8.
>   Default:: [] (Empty list)
>
> A list containing the settings for all template engines to be used with Django. Each item of the list is a dictionary containing the options for an individual engine.

Take the code below as an example or guide.

```
TEMPLATES = [    
        {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',   
            'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '<enter here your custom templates directory')], # For those who wants to have a custom place for templates in their Django apps/projects.
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

EDIT: Added an example, just in case.

Comment: After OP confirm that my question comment was their solution, I post here the answer. Be happy.

Comment: Oh now I saw this. Nice. Sorry for misunderstanding earlier. You get the +100 bounty. :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hmmm. Don't worry. You'll still get the +100 bounty for helping me. I'll be able to award the bounty in 23 hours from now according to StackOverflow.

Comment: Any case, I'm glad to help to you. Regards.